# Does Breaker Bay Grid reduce the cost of ICE hosted on Awakening Center

Tags: android-netrunner

I have [Breaker Bay Grid](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Breaker%20Bay%20Grid) in a server, along with [Awakening Center](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Awakening%20Center) hosting a [Janus 1.0](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=Janus%201.0).

Does Janus 1.0 count as "in" the server for the purposes of Breaker Bay Grid's cost reduction?  Equivalently, does Janus cost 8 credits or just 3?

---

Breaker Bay Grid has the ability:

> The rez cost of cards in this server is lowered by 5.

Awakening Center has the abilities:

> Awakening Center can host bioroid ice (each piece is installed
>   facedown, ignoring all install costs).
>
> Whenever the Runner passes all of the ice protecting this server, you
>   may rez a piece of ice on Awakening Center, lowering the rez cost by
>   7 [credits], to force the Runner to encounter it. Trash that ice after the 
>   run is completed.

Normally Breaker Bay doesn't work on ICE because ICE is protecting the server rather than "in" it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the FAQ on Awakening Center:

> Ice on Awakening Center are in the server and do not count as ice
>   protecting the server.

So, the ICE on the awakening center do get the cost reduction from Breaker Bay Grid.  Janus 1.0 would only cost 3 credits to rez in this situation.